# Fire custom event inside timeout

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to fire an event inside a timeout function but it's not working. I know in aura is necessary to wrap the timeout with getCallback() but I don't know the equivalent in lwc.

```
this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('searchby', { detail: value || '' });
            this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);

        }, 300);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the `this` binding in your setTimeout needs to be explicitly set. Try this:

```
this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('searchby', { detail: value || '' });
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}.bind(this), 300);
```

The `this` in `this.dispatchEvent` should now refer to the component instead of the setTimeout context

Comment: Technically speaking, you could just use an arrow function, then? Your answer seems reasonable, though.

Comment: I tend to avoid using arrow functions that use `this` because I've ran into too many situation where someone thought that arrow functions were only a syntax change and didn't realize that they change how `this` is bound. I prefer to the explicitness of `bind`. However, yes an arrow function should also fix the issue